# is possible to filter range of number in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have seven div in html, if i load html first all div display in browser.i use html,css,and javascript (jquery)

```
<section>
  <a href="#">ALL</a> 
  <a href="#">less than 3</a>
  <a href="#">between 2 and 5</a>
  <a href="#">greater than 5</a>

</section>

<div data-filter="1">one</div>
<div data-filter="2">two</div>
<div data-filter="3">three</div>
<div data-filter="4">four</div>
<div data-filter="5">five</div>
<div data-filter="6">six</div>
<div data-filter="7">seven</div>
```

following code above, if I click **all** then all div show on screen,if i click **less than 3** then div only show div **one and two**, and if i click **grater than 5** then div show **six and seven**

**my question** how i achieve that,its possible ?

thanks

Comment: Yes that's possible. What do you have so far?

Comment: Use more data attributes that javascript can understand, as "ALL", "less than" etc. means nothing in code.

Comment: Find the elements with the attribute, loop through, compare value, show/hide. TADA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nuAuk/)

HTML:

```
<section id="mysection">
  <a href="#">ALL</a> 
  <a data-max="3" href="#">less than 3</a>
  <a data-min="2" data-max="5" href="#">between 2 and 5</a>
  <a data-min="5" href="#">greater than 5</a>
</section>
<section id="target">
    <div data-filter="1">one</div>
    <div data-filter="2">two</div>
    <div data-filter="3">three</div>
    <div data-filter="4">four</div>
    <div data-filter="5">five</div>
    <div data-filter="6">six</div>
    <div data-filter="7">seven</div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
var els = document.getElementById('target').children;
document.getElementById('mysection').onclick = function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a') return;
    var min = +(e.target.getAttribute('data-min') || -Infinity),
        max = +(e.target.getAttribute('data-max') || Infinity);
    for(var i=0, l=els.length; i<l; ++i) {
        var num = +els[i].getAttribute('data-filter');
        els[i].style.display = min < num && num < max ? '' : 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Really this all just comes down to understanding the basics of jQuery. A very simple function to accomplish this might look like:

```
function show(start, end) {
    target = $('#target')
    on = target.children().slice(start, end)
    on.show()
    target.children().not(on).hide()
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle demonstrating it](http://jsfiddle.net/5qkaa/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<section>
  <a href="#" onclick="show(0)">ALL</a> 
  <a href="#" onclick="show(1)">less than 3</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="show(2)">between 2 and 5</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="show(3)">greater than 5</a>

</section>

<div data-filter="1" class="one all ltt">one</div>
<div data-filter="2" class="two all ltt">two</div>
<div data-filter="3" class="three all btf">three</div>
<div data-filter="4" class="four all gtt btf">four</div>
<div data-filter="5" class="five all gtt btf">five</div>
<div data-filter="6" class="six all gtt btf gtf">six</div>
<div data-filter="7" class="seven all gtt gtf">seven</div>

<script>
function show(var numbr )
{
switch (numbr)
{
 case 0:
 document.getElementByClass("all").show()
break;
 case 1:
 document.getElementByClass("llt").show()
break;
 case 2:
 document.getElementByClass("ggt").show()
break;
 case 3:
 document.getElementByClass("gtf").show()
break;
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use .gt() and .lt() here:
use following code
 <section>
        <a href="#" id="1">ALL</a>
        <a href="#" id="2">less than 3</a>
        <a href="#" id="3">between 2 and 5</a>
        <a href="#" id="4">greater than 5</a>

    </section>

    <div data-filter="1">one</div>
    <div data-filter="2">two</div>
    <div data-filter="3">three</div>
    <div data-filter="4">four</div>
    <div data-filter="5">five</div>
    <div data-filter="6">six</div>
    <div data-filter="7">seven</div>

 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("a").on("click", function () {
            var anchorId = $(this).attr("id");

            switch (anchorId) {
                case "2":
                    $("div:lt(3)").show();
                    $("div:gt(2)").hide();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    $("div").hide();
                    $("div:lt(6):gt(1)").show();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    $("div:gt(5)").show();
                    $("div:lt(6)").hide();
                    break;
                default:
                    $("div").show();
                    break;
            }
        });
 });

 Don't forget to accept the answer if it works :)
```